# Android RSS Reader Description Problems

Tags: java, android, rss

I'm building a simple RSS reader for android, and I'm having a bit of a problem with the top description of the RSS..the RSS file goes something like this:

```
<rss>
<channel>
<title>myTitle</title>
<description>desc</description>
<link>myLink</link>
<lastbuilddate>date</lastbuilddate>
<item>
*ITEM1
</item>
<item>
*ITEM2
</item>

...
...

...
</channel>
</rss>
```

The problem I have is that this is displaying the top description of the RSS channel (myTitle, desc, myLink, date, etc.), and not displaying the first item. I presume this is because the translator is looking for a , but the first one is not until the end of the first item?

Any help with this?
I used the SAX Implementation, with help from this tutorial: http://www.ingeniumblog.net/2012/01/making-a-slick-rss-reader-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Try using  [Android Rome feed reader](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/&ei=p5WFT9SbBovssgb-17ivBg&usg=AFQjCNHD3vH2Z7UfeX8JKR2Zbhh_wde_dQ) is a bit slow but works well and handles all kinds of RSS feeds( RSS 2.0 and Atom mainly).